# Crash in the depths of Alamofire

Tags: ios, crash, alamofire, exc-bad-access

I'm struggling to debug a crash that we're seeing in Alamofire. To make things more difficult this is an SDK that we're providing to a client and it's then crashing in their production app. As far as I'm aware so far this isn't reproducible or being noticed by users, it's just showing up in the client's crash logs.

To add further complication, we statically build our framework together with a number of frameworks, Alamofire included, that's then delivered to the client who pulls it into their app. Our SDK is 100% Swift, whereas the client's is a mix of Objective-C and Swift.

Crash log is as follows with a few identifiers obfuscated:

```
# Platform: ios
# Session ID: undefined
# Date: 2018-07-20T07:57:00Z
# OS Version: 11.4.0 (15F79)
# Device: iPhone 8 Plus
# RAM Free: 6%
# Disk Free: 67.5%

#1. Crashed: com.example.RequestQueue
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1842497f4 objc_object::release() + 16
1  MYSDK                         0x101f7bcb8 _T09Alamofire15DownloadRequestC8responseACXDSo13DispatchQueueCSg5queue_x0D10SerializeryAA0B8ResponseVy16SerializedObjectQzGc17completionHandlertAA0biH8ProtocolRzlFyycfU_yycfU_AA0biH0VyypG_Tg5TA + 132
2  MYSDK                         0x101f7bcb8 _T09Alamofire15DownloadRequestC8responseACXDSo13DispatchQueueCSg5queue_x0D10SerializeryAA0B8ResponseVy16SerializedObjectQzGc17completionHandlertAA0biH8ProtocolRzlFyycfU_yycfU_AA0biH0VyypG_Tg5TA + 132
3  libswiftCore.dylib             0x102488f10 _swift_release_dealloc + 28
4  MYSDK                         0x101f7bc20 _T09Alamofire16DownloadResponseVyypGWh0_ + 144
5  libswiftCore.dylib             0x102488f10 _swift_release_dealloc + 28
6  libsystem_blocks.dylib         0x184a04a5c _Block_release + 152
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x184964a60 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x1849a31d4 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain$VARIANT$armv81 + 568
9  libdispatch.dylib              0x1849a3af8 _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$armv81 + 328
10 libdispatch.dylib              0x1849a449c _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh$VARIANT$armv81 + 332
11 libdispatch.dylib              0x1849ac46c _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread$VARIANT$armv81 + 612
12 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x184c97e70 _pthread_wqthread + 860
13 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x184c97b08 start_wqthread + 4
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely there's a crash in a `response` closure after a `download` call. Looks like this is using a `DownloadResponseSerializer<Any>`, which is the type used for a JSON response. I'm not sure why it would be crashing on `release()`, but my guess is this is a release after free issue.

Comment: Thanks for the response (sorry for the delay!) Yes that's what I'm thinking, it's tricky to track down where it's happening and whether it's coming from our code or the client's, and given it's all nice Swift with ARC - why there'd be a memory issue anyway. Haven't managed to track it down yet anyway!